# How to prevent VoiceOver cursor from resetting its position on layout change

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I am working on making our app more accessible, and am running into an issue with VoiceOver.

I have a view controller that has a table view and a horizontal scroll view that animates every 5 seconds to show something else. (Like what the Apple App Store app does on it's Featured Page where views slide in every few seconds)

The problem is that if I have selected a table view cell and VoiceOver is reading it out, the moment it animates to the next view, the VoiceOver cursor resets to the top of the nav bar.

Looking at the Apple App Store, there is a way to avoid this. I would like it to not reset its position when another view shows.

Any suggestions here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use UIAccessibilityPostNotification and pass the parameter of the element you want selected:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,viewToSelect);
```